# sql query one field twice on one table using same condition with different values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `accounts`

I have fields called

```
id  
provider
type
account_name
```

they are structured as

```
id - int(12)
provider -int(12)
type - int(12)
account_name - Varchar(25)
```

I think a join or subquery could work but cant get it work
The aim is i want to display providers that have both `type=2 and type=5 ORDER By account_name`

eg shows companies that sell both real estate and loans

```
Select * from accounts WHERE type = 2 and type=5
```

I know the above doesnt work but its kind the mindset that i need.
Id appreciate any help in getting this working.

The mysql output result should look like this in a single line.

Eg

Provider  Account_Name1(this matched 2)  Account_Name2(Matched 5) 
Johnson - Johnson Real Estate - Johnson Loans

Comment: Presumably you have a `providers` table also?

Comment: i have one table, it should be where type=2 and type=5 not ID , type is the field that is looked up twice

Comment: So when you say you want to display "providers" what exactly do you want to display, the `provider int`?

Comment: well look at below answer 1, i got it kind of working as i mentioned below but i do not have the output i require as mentioned?

Comment: any chance anyone can help answer my question as the solution below isnt exactly what i require??

Answer (score 4):

This should look up providers that have both `id` 2 and 5:

```
select  provider
from    accounts
where   id in (2,5)
group by
        provider
having  count(distinct id) = 2
```

Comment: i fixed it up and got this to work - select  *
from    accounts
where   type in (2,5)
group by
        provider
having  count(distinct type) = 2    , when i output this result, it will display in a table and display just wondering how could i output the following. The provider Johnson, account_name when type =2 is Johnson Real Estate, account_name when type =5 is Johnson Loans. How do i set the sql so both of these values can be outputed from mysql in a single line. Eg Provider Account_Name1 Account_Name2  - Johnson - Johnson Real Estate - Johnson Loans

Comment: +10 you as you helped me with another issue i had from your code

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct acc2.provider,acc2.account_name,acc5.account_name
from accounts acc2 inner join accounts acc5 on acc2.provider=acc5.provider
where acc2.type = 2 and acc5.type = 5
```

This makes a bit of an assumption that there won't be duplicate `provider`/`type` combinations. eg One provider having multiple rows having the same `type`. In fact the `distinct` isn't necessary if the data conforms to that requirement.

I would also say as an aside that this is a somewhat strange table, although I don't know the full story. This seems to be a table used to associate providers with account types. And each association of provider and account type can have an Account_Name. I would think this would be better represented by 3 tables.

```
TABLE Provider (
   ID INT PK
   Name VARHCAR(50)
)

TABLE AccountType (
   ID INT
   AccountType VARCHAR(50)
)

TABLE ProviderAccountType (
   ProviderID PK FK
   AccountTypeID PK FK
   AccountName VARCHAR(50)
)
```

Comment: just for your information it is setup that way actually, i just didnt mention it because the db design is a little complex so +10 for your answer. I wonder if i had another field to limit the duplicates of provider, eg WHERE realestatetype='residential' and is associated with type=2 , where would i add this to your initial query as that works great. Thanks so much by the way

Comment: anyways i solved it myself, thank you so much, +20 again, first time i have used stackoverflow, its brilliant!

Comment: @JohnSmith If an answer has helped then you should mark it with the tick to the left ;) Glad you solved your problem